# Parsing MySQL Historian Format

Tags: mysql, volttron

We are using VOLTTRON MySQL Historian to save meter readings to the MySQL database. The meter readings are saved in “value string” in a format similar to JSON:

`[{'W_primary': 19003.677734375, 'freq': 60.01973342895508, 'pf': -0.9935459494590759}, {'W_primary': {'units': 'W ', 'tz': 'PT', 'type': 'float'}, 'freq': {'units': 'Hz', 'tz': 'PT', 'type': 'float'}, 'pf': {'units': u'', 'tz': 'PT', 'type': 'float'}}]`

Our goal is to be able to export this data both for use in VOLTTRON and external to the VOLTTRON environment. Are there python scripts/libraries for parsing this data direct from the MySQL database, outside of VOLTTRON? For instance, one application may be to use a Labview tool to customize the data topics/timeframe to export to csv (e.g. All frequency data from a given day). Because the format is not true JSON, we can't use the JSON Function Reference (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-function-reference.html).

Alternatively, is there a way for the Historian to write to the database in a more straightforward column format?

Note: we are using VOLTTRON 2.0. Has this functionality changed in more recent versions?

Comment: If the single quotes were double quotes I am fairly sure that would be valid JSON

Comment: And if it was JSON then pretty much everything has a way of converting it from and to native data structures

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL historian didn't exist until VOLTTRON 3.0. I'm not even sure how you  made this work as the message bus changed significantly from 2 to 3. There is a compatibility layer but it is for running V2 agents on V3 and not the other way around.

The JSON in your question is what is actually published by the driver to the "all" topic for a device. The first item is a map of point names to topics and the second items is a map of point names to metadata.

In 3 and beyond a Historian will pick this up and match up the point values to the complete topic for the point. What you should see in the database is a table of topics to values. How those values are stored is up to the specific historian implementation (Mongo vs MySQL vs Crate vs SQLite) but it will be a map of point topics to values.

In newer versions of VOLTTRON we've dropped sMap as the primary way of gathering data from devices. All device interaction now happens through the Master Driver Agent. The CSV file used to describe the device is mostly unchanged. The per device configuration is now stored in JSON in a one file per device format.

I strongly recommend updating to VOLTTRON 4. There are many improvements to the platform since 2.

EDIT: I should also mention that the form that messages take changed from 2 to 3 and that is probably what is confusing the historian.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. We have updated to VOLTTRON 4.1 and this has solved our data column issues. The issue was a mismatch in versions between the base VOLTTRON platform and some of the agents we had brought in from newer versions..